# about "informieren"

Tags: verb, verb-usage

Is "informieren" always a transitive verb? According to whatever dictionary I can find, that seems to be the case. However, consider the following definition:

> ein Lexikon, das über alles Wichtige und Interessante der verschiedenen (Wissens)Bereiche **informiert**

Is it wrong?

Comment: Which dictionaries are you referring to?

Comment: Langenschedit Großwörterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache

Comment: That dictionary doesn't use the terms *transitive* or *intransitive* (German dictionaries usually don't); instead it uses indications like *jemanden (über etwas) informieren*. Although I guess your point remains: on what basis are complements classified as optional (via parentheses).

Comment: Oops! I misunderstood your request. The said dictionary is what the quoted definition is from. I mean, pretty well every English-German dictionary has the transitive label for "informieren," including Langenscheidt's Standard Dictionary.

Comment: In your example, "jemanden (über etwas) informieren."  the "jemanden" is not in parentheses, indicating it is obligatory. That in turn means "informieren" is transitive.

Comment: @DavidVogt I just checked Langenschedit Großwörterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache. It does indicate whether a verb is transitve and/or intransitive, by means of [Vt/i], [Vt] and [Vi[.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a misunderstanding. A transitive verb is one, which **allows** an (typically: accusative) object, it does not **mandate** that object. So yes, *informieren* is transitive and is also often used in a reflexive way as in

> Ich informiere mich über den aktuellen Stand.

Comment: Could you explain why "essen" has an intransitive label? Why the difference?

Comment: @Apollyon: There are two meanings of the verb, from which the intransitive just describes the process of eating, compare e. g. [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/essen).

Comment: I am not sure If I really understand that. Couldn't "informieren" also describe, in your words, "the process of" informing? Delivering a piece of information is a process after all.

Answer (score 0):

*Informieren* is in fact in all cases a *transitive* verb. The second most common use is probably *reflexive*, when someone acquires certain knowledge for himself.

You may encounter some rare cases of usage without an object (note this doesn't necessarily mean the verb is intransitive), as in your example. This is when the object (who was informed) is implicitely obvious, as in your example (the reader) or in

> Die Tagesschau informiert täglich mehrmals über das Weltgeschehen

(the viewer)

> Der Regierungssprecher informierte über die aktuellen Vorgänge im Kabinett

(the public)

Comment: Why isn't an intransitive label listed for "informieren" when an intransitive label is listed for "essen"? Any rantionale?

Comment: This answer sounds like transitivity/intransitivity of a verb is rather a semantic property than a grammatical one. Not sure whether that is the intention.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it wrong?

No. German is pretty chatty and to fight that, we use all kind of ellipses.

- *Aldi wirbt nicht, Aldi informiert (uns)!*

In practice, no one ever adds that *uns*. This for brevity.

Comment: I think it's more than that in your example; being as structurally similar in both parts of the sentence as possible also has an important part there. Moreover, I wouldn't say that it's "uns" that is ellipsed-away; "Aldi informiert" rather sounds like *everyone* is getting informed, rather than just "us".